# Is there an easy way to unsubscribe from a "Sign in with Apple" login

Tags: email, apple-id, accounts

I use the "Sign in with Apple" feature a lot because it allows you to hide your email from the app/website you use it on, and also generates a unique email for each app or website. Theoretically this protects your email and also allows you to easily completely drop communication an app or website by invalidating the unique email.

How can I completely stop an app or website from emailing me when I have used "Sign in with Apple?" I would specifically like to avoid using the "unsubscribe" option provided from the website itself—I want to remove communication from this company on a more nuclear and complete level. In other words, I want to disable the unique email and cut communication off completely.

One option would be to block all emails that are sent to the unique address using an email filter. However, this seems like more of a workaround rather than a solution. Has Apple ever provided a way to easily stop communication from an app or website that uses "Sign in with Apple?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426

On an iPhone, in the Settings app, under Apple ID -> Password & Security -> Apps Using Apple ID, you can find this menu, which will allow you to disable forwarding from the private relay service. [image: Apps Using Apple ID menu]

On a computer, you can access these same settings at the [Apple ID website](http://appleid.apple.com/account/manage).

- Click on "Manage apps & websites" within the Securtity part
- Click on the website/app you want to disable
- Click on "Turn Off" (to prevent mails) or "Stop using AppleID" (to delete it)